# How does SQL Server figure out the entered date's format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, date-format

I use SQL Server 2014 Developer. Assume I have this scenario where I filter payment date of an Invoice

```
select * 
from Invoices 
where PaymentDate > '1/2/2012'
```

In the `Invoice` table, `PaymentDate` is in the format of **2012-01-08 00:00:00**     `( YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS )`

But RHS operand of the where is `1/2/2012` So, how does SQL know if this in the format of `M/D/YYYY` or `D/M/YYYY` ?

Comment: @MitchWheat But it to perform comparison it should know in 1/2/2012 , 1= month 2=date  because if it swaps those two as 1 = date and 2 = moth then results of the select statement would be different?

Comment: irrelevant if you follow the best practice advice, but yes it depends on your locale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Datetimes don't have a format (other than binary): they are (hopefully) being stored as [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and not strings.  Don't confuse presentation with representation.

When you have a string literal, `'1/2/2012'`, SQL Server interprets via your locale.

Best practice to always use (and export) dates in the ISO 8601 format `yyyy-MM-dd` (`yyyyMMdd`).

See [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
[What date/time literal formats are LANGUAGE and DATEFORMAT safe?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe)

Comment: For  the ISO recommendation +1